# PHP string functions not working as expected on numbers cast as string

Tags: php, string, postal-code

I have the following code which places a space in postcode.

```
(string)$postcode = $row['postcode'];
$first = substr($postcode, strlen($postcode)-3);
$second = substr($postcode, strlen($first));
$postcode = $first . ' ' . $second;
```

The code works fine for most codes, except some. ie

PN45HA
70448

And i can't understand why?  Can anyone shine a light on this?

Thankyou

Comment: `(string)$postcode = $row['postcode'];` should be: `$postcode = (string)$row['postcode'];`

Comment: What is your expected and what the actual output? (give two examples, one working, one erroneous)

Comment: @Yoshi - you really should post that as an answer.

Comment: Input might be something like HX37NN and Output something like HX3 7NN, ie a space 3 spaces from the right in every postcode

Answer (score 4):

Don't really understand the question, but if it's about the space, this will work:

```
$postcode = 'PN45HA70448';
$postcode = substr($postcode, 0, -3) . ' ' . substr($postcode, -3);
// PN45HA70 448
```

Comment: huh? I guess from the format that it is already a string so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yep the position of the cast makes no difference.  Something like because there's lots of different types of postcodes

Comment: Thanks Yoshi - a lot quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = substr($postcode, 0, -3);
$second = substr($postcode, -3);
$postcode = $first . ' ' . $second;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$code = 'PN45HA 70448'
$first = substr($postcode, strlen($postcode)-3); // 448
$second = substr($postcode, strlen($first)); // PN45HA 70
$postcode = $first . ' ' . $second; // PN45HA 70 448
```

The problem is that not all of your postcodes are simple 6 character postcodes. You're simply adding  space before the last 3 characters in whatever string you happen to pass in.

What you may need to do is use a regex:

```
$code = preg_replace('/([A-Z][0-9][A-Z])\s*([0-9][A-Z][0-9])/', '\1 \2', $code);
```

This'll take any string which looks like a postcode, with optional spaces between the two halves, and puts in a single space.